# Undefined Index in File upload php script

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I am trying to create a page for a site that I am working on, which allows users to upload a logo image for a vendor while adding other information about that vendor to a database.  The filename gets stored in a mysql database and the image is supposed to be uploaded to ./graphics to used in another place on the site.

The mysql part is working perfectly at this point, but I can't seem to get the image to upload to ./graphics.

I checked the Apache error log and found the following...

```
[Fri Aug 09 07:18:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VendorLogo in /var/www/labconnect2/addvendor.php on line 72, referer: http://localhost/labconnect2/addvendor.php
[Fri Aug 09 07:18:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VendorLogo in /var/www/labconnect2/addvendor.php on line 74, referer: http://localhost/labconnect2/addvendor.php
[Fri Aug 09 07:18:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VendorLogo in /var/www/labconnect2/addvendor.php on line 75, referer: http://localhost/labconnect2/addvendor.php
[Fri Aug 09 07:18:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VendorLogo in /var/www/labconnect2/addvendor.php on line 76, referer: http://localhost/labconnect2/addvendor.php
[Fri Aug 09 07:18:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VendorLogo in /var/www/labconnect2/addvendor.php on line 77, referer: http://localhost/labconnect2/addvendor.php
[Fri Aug 09 07:18:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VendorLogo in /var/www/labconnect2/addvendor.php on line 78, referer: http://localhost/labconnect2/addvendor.php
[Fri Aug 09 07:18:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VendorLogo in /var/www/labconnect2/addvendor.php on line 79, referer: http://localhost/labconnect2/addvendor.php
[Fri Aug 09 07:18:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VendorLogo in /var/www/labconnect2/addvendor.php on line 117, referer: http://localhost/labconnect2/addvendor.php
```

So I checked and double checked my form code and verified the name attribute in the form tag. I also checked to make sure the the $_FILES was referencing that name properly, and it is (as far as I can tell).

I did some research and found that this could be a result of the max upload size and max post size parameters in the php.ini, so I double checked that and they are both set to 2m.

I am sure that this "undefined index" error is the reason that the file is not uploading, but I cannot seem to find what is wrong with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Add New vendor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/addnew.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="box">
        <div id="exit">
            <h2><a href="./index.php">X</a></h2>        
        </div>

        <div id="form">

            <form name="new_entry" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Name 
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="vendor">
                <br>
                <br>
                Support Website for Vendor
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="SupportSite">
                <br>
                <br>
                Phone Number for Support
                <br>
                <input type="tel" name="SupportNum">
                <br>
                <br>
                Main Website for Vendor
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="MainSite">
                <br>
                <br>
                Notes
                <br>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="255" wrap="hard" name="notes"></textarea>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p>Upload Logo:    <input type="file" name="VendorLogo"> </p>
                <p><em>PNG images with transparent backgrounds are best.</em></p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit">


            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

    <?php

        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','ssctechlab','paracon','ssctechlab');

        //check connection
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "failed to connect to MySQL Server: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        };

        //echo 'Connected... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";


        //Image Upload
                    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            if ((($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["size"] < 20000)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
              {
              if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["error"] . "<br>";
                }
              else
                {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

                if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["name"]))
                 {
                 echo $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                 }
                else
                 {
                 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["tmp_name"],
                 "upload/" . $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["name"]);
                 echo "Stored in: " . "graphics/" . $_FILES["VendorLogo"]["name"];
                 }
                }
              }
            else
              {
              echo "Invalid file";
              }

    //Insert info into VendorInfo Table
        $vendor = $_POST["vendor"];
        $SupportSite = $_POST["SupportSite"];
        $SupportNum = $_POST["SupportNum"];
        $MainSite = $_POST["MainSite"];
        $notes = $_POST["notes"];
        $VendorLogo = ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["name"]);



        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO VendorInfo VALUES('','$VendorLogo','$vendor','$SupportSite','$SupportNum','$MainSite','$notes')");


        mysqli_close($con);

        //header('Location: ./index.php')

    ?>
</body>
```

By the way, this is based code I got from w3schools.com.  I am still a total noob so go easy on me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you use an array index that is not set. You need to make sure that it exists before using it:

```
if ( ! isset($_FILES["VendorLogo"])) {
    die('VendorLogo is not set...');
}
```

Comment: I got rid of the index error based on this.  The problem was actually in that "explode" function.  So I stored ($_FILES["VendorLogo"]["name"])  and then used it in the explode function like so...  explode( . , $filename).  Unfortunately, the image is still not uploading for some reason, but I will go ahead and give you credit for this one, because the index errors are in fact gone.